# xamarin ui test won't run any of my tests

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin.uitest

After a visual studio update and xcode update I'm unable to run my xamarin ui tests. No idea why of how this happend...

I get the following exception:

```
SetUp : System.Exception : ApkFile or InstalledApp has not been configured.

at Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.AndroidAppConfiguration.Verify () [0x0003d] in <2a16c16730a54859bda72c6bc1c728f7>:0
 at Xamarin.UITest.Android.LocalAndroidAppInitializer.VerifyConfiguration () [0x00008] in <2a16c16730a54859bda72c6bc1c728f7>:0
 at Xamarin.UITest.Android.AndroidApp..ctor (Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.IAndroidAppConfiguration appConfiguration, Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Execution.IExecutor executor) [0x000c3] in <2a16c16730a54859bda72c6bc1c728f7>:0
 at Xamarin.UITest.Android.AndroidApp..ctor (Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.IAndroidAppConfiguration appConfiguration) [0x00000] in <2a16c16730a54859bda72c6bc1c728f7>:0
 at Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.AndroidAppConfigurator.StartApp (Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.AppDataMode appDataMode) [0x00017] in <2a16c16730a54859bda72c6bc1c728f7>:0
 at UniversalApp.UITests.AppInitializer.StartApp (Xamarin.UITest.Platform platform) [0x0000a] in /Users/testing/backend/src/UniversalApp.UITests/AppInitializer.cs:23
 at UniversalApp.UITests.DummyTests.BeforeEachTest () [0x00001] in /Users/testing/backend/src/UniversalApp.UITests/DummyTests.cs:26
 at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
 at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x0003b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:305
```

[UPDATE]

I am now able to run the android tests but not the ios test now I get the error Unable to determine simulator version for

Comment: Is this happened on VS 2019?@John

Comment: Yeah indeed previous I had vs 2017

Comment: But I un-installed it and now I'am using vs 2017 again. No difference

Comment: Here is an sample (https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UsingUITest/).Need to know  whether it can run successsfully.

Comment: Junior - The test never had any problems, now I was able to get them working on android. ios is still a problem. It can't determine the simulator version

Comment: Okey, if solved it ,you can post an answer for it.If can not determini the simulator version,suggest refer to this(https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/140441/reporting-bugs-on-xamarin-uitest-unable-to-determine-simulator-version-for-simulator-on-ios-12) may be helpful.This maybe another question,you can create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Xamarin ui test won't work very well with xcode 10.2. I downgraded to version 10.1 and android works fine again.